# How to get a list of page objects using Jsoup

Tags: kotlin, web-crawler, jsoup

I've been working with Jsoup for a long time, and I managed to capture it on several sites, but there's one that I can't do at all, I've tried passing almost all possible ids and I can't return the result list.

My code structure is very simple:

```
fun execute(beer: String, record: Int = 100): WebsiteEntity {
    val products = arrayListOf<ProductEntity>()
    var document: Document? = null

    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("https://mercado.carrefour.com.br/s?q=heineken&sort=score_desc&page=0").get()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return getWebsiteEntity(products)
    }

    for (item in document.select(".grid .grid-cols-2")) {
        products.add(
            ProductEntity(
                name = "",
                price = "",
                partner = "",
                url = "",
                image = "",
                percent = "",
                websiteName = ""
            )
        )
    }
    return getWebsiteEntity(products)
}
```

I tried to get the value of the grid:

```
"grid grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-4"
```

but it doesn't return anything.

[image: evidência]

Answer (score 0):

Does the website use Javascript to populate the page? If so, Jsoup won't work for you. From [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-with-jsoup):

> Bear in mind that jsoup interprets HTML only — it does not interpret JavaScript. Therefore changes to the DOM that would normally take place after page loads in a JavaScript-enabled browser will not be seen in jsoup.

As for alternatives that DO run full browser engines, the one that people seem to recommend these days for Java is [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/java/), though I've never used it myself.